# How can I update Tasks via API in an org with 'Shared Activities' enabled?

Tags: apex, tasks, shared-activities

“I've adapted Scott Hammeter's dandy code (http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2009/10/06/associate-email-to-salesforce-task-to-opportunity/) so I can relate the tasks created by inbound Email-to-Salesforce emails to active campaigns rather than to open opportunities. The heart of the solution is a constructor in a class called by a beforeInsert task trigger. The construct queries for campaigns related to the contact identified in the task's WhoId:

```
// Associates a new Task generated by Email to Salesforce to an open opportunity, if one exists for the Account
public void AssociateCampaign(Task[] tasks)
{

    /***************
    * Variables
    ***************/
    list<Task> l_Tasks = new list<Task>(); // Tasks to update
    set<ID> s_ContactIDs = new set<ID>(); // Set of Contact IDs

    /***************
    * Initial Loop
    ***************/
    for(Task t:tasks) {

        // Add Task to working list and collect the Contact ID
        if (t.WhatId == null && t.Subject.startsWith('Email:') && t.WhoId != null) {
            // only for Contacts
            if (String.valueOf(t.WhoId).startsWith('003')){
                l_Tasks.add(t);
                s_ContactIDs.add(t.WhoId);
            }
        }

    }

    /***************
    * Create Maps
    ***************/
    // Maps Contact ID to a Campaign ID
    map<ID, ID> map_cID_to_camID = new map<ID, ID>();
        // Query for the Contact's active Campaigns. Sort CampaignMember by CreatedDate DESC so the Task gets assigned to the campaign to which contact was most recently added
        for (CampaignMember cm:[select Id, CampaignId, ContactId, CreatedDate
                                         from CampaignMember
                                         where ContactId in :s_ContactIDs
                                         AND Campaign.IsActive = TRUE
                                         order by CreatedDate DESC
                                         ]) {
            map_cID_to_camID.put(cm.ContactId, cm.CampaignId);
            System.debug('ContactId - CampaignId:' + map_cId_to_camId);
        }

    /***************
    * Process Records
    ***************/
    for (Task t:l_Tasks) {

        // If the Contact has a campaign mapped to it, update the Task with that campaign
        if (map_cID_to_camID.get(t.WhoId) != null) {
            t.WhatId = map_cID_to_camID.get(t.WhoId);

        }
    }
```

This works as intended in orgs where the Shared Activities feature has not been enabled: a task created from an Email-to-Salesforce email has the contact's most recent active campaign in the WhatId (label: "Related To") field.

In orgs with Shared Activities enabled, the code fails to do this and WhatId remains null. Research makes me think that the code needs to insert a TaskRelation object for each Task object, with values
AccountId = cm.Contact.AccountId
IsWhat = TRUE
TaskId = Task.Id
RelationId = cm.CampaignId.

Has anyone else experienced this issue of needing to insert or update TaskRelation objects in order to populate Task.WhatId through the API?”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have some insight on this. Let me know if this helps.

In my experience (with the `WhoId`, not the `WhatId`), I had to do the following:

On an initial `INSERT`, I would populate the `Task` and respective `WhoId`. If there were any other records I needed to related, I would use the `TaskRelation` object using the newly insert `Task` record's Id.

What happens on the back end, with Shared Activities on, is whatever you marked as the `WhoId` gets a `TaskRelation` record behind the scenes. How do I know that? Well, let me go over the `UPDATE` scenario.

On an update of a `Task` you cannot change the `WhoId` or the `WhatId` - throws an exception. However, if you remove the `TaskRelation` records that contain the `WhatId` or `WhoId`, the next `TaskRelation` record will take its place.

Having said that, if you need to remove all of the other related records to a Task, be sure to exclude the `WhoId` and the `WhatId`.

To relate another record to a `Task`, you simply add another `TaskRelation` record.

I hope that clarifies things.